How to make a mutable map and avoid deprecations when creating it
I have some scala code that complains that   method + in trait MapOps is deprecated (since 2.13.0)
code creates a map
var map : Map[String,Any] = Map()
...
map += ("foo" -> "baa", "wibble" -> "wobble")

the map returned by this method needs to be immutable.
Some googling implies += is not de rigueur and that addOne() should be used, but Map() does not have addOne().  Cloud only deployments so I don't get any help from my IDE.
How can I create a mutable map add to it and then return an immutable map?  In a way that is idiomatic and not subject to deprecation.


How can I create a mutable map add to it and then return an immutable map?

You can transform a mutable Map into immutable one with .toMap:
val map: mutable.Map[String,Any] = mutable.Map()
map += ("foo" -> "baa")
val map1: immutable.Map[String, Any] = map.toMap

or
val map: mutable.Map[String,Any] = mutable.Map()
val map1: immutable.Map[String, Any] = (map += ("foo" -> "baa")).toMap

Converting mutable to immutable map
mutable.Map += is not deprecated, it's collection.Map += that is deprecated.
collection.Map is a parent for mutable.Map and immutable.Map.
Also it's not clear why immutable Map is not enough for you:
val map : immutable.Map[String,Any] = immutable.Map()
val map1: immutable.Map[String, Any] = map + ("foo" -> "baa")

or just
val map : Map[String,Any] = Map()
val map1: Map[String, Any] = map + ("foo" -> "baa")

Please notice that most probably you don't need vars.
And maybe you can work with Map[String,String], not Map[String,Any].

method + in trait MapOps is deprecated (since 2.13.0)  if I use map + ()   or map += ()

It seems that the =+ is not deprecated (thanks Dmytro)
But double map entries like this
map += ("foo" -> "baa", "wibble" -> "wobble")

Need to be converted to single entries
map += ("foo" -> "baa")
map += ("wibble" -> "wobble")


You can write one-liner map ++= Seq("foo" -> "baa", "wibble" -> "wobble")
